# update table with 4 columns specified, but only 2 columns are available

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-update

I have one table called test, which has 4 columns:

```
id     INT
v_out  INT
v_in   INT
label  CHARACTER
```

I'm trying to update the table with the following query:

```
String sql = "
    update
        test
    set
        v_out = temp.outV
        , v_in = temp.inV
        , label = temp.label
    from (
            values(
                (1,234,235,'abc')
                ,(2,234,5585,'def')
            )
        ) as temp (e_id, outV, inV, label)
    where
        id = temp.e_id
";
```

When I execute it, I got the error:

org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR:

```
 table "temp" has 2 columns available but 4 columns specified
```

Whats the problem, and how can i solve it?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server? They are *not* the same thing.

Comment: Your question is tagged "mysql" and "sql-server".  The error is from Postgres.  You seem very confused.  First, figure out which database you are using.

Comment: I am using postgresql.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I've edited your original question to provide more readability. Next time please do the formatting when you post a question and add the proper tags. Provide all necessary information which can help to solve your problem. Please read the following articles: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: sorry, i m new to this, i will read and later when i ask questions, i will follow the rule. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values for the `values` clause must not be enclosed in parentheses:

```
values (
    (1,234,235,'abc'), (2,234,5585,'def')
)
```

creates a single row with two columns. Each column being an anonymous "record" with 4 fields.

What you want is:

```
from (
        values 
            (1,234,235,'abc'), 
            (2,234,5585,'def')
    ) as temp (e_id, outV, inV, label)
```

SQLFiddle showing the difference: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/d41d8/2763

This behavior is documented, but that is quite hard to find: 
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/rowtypes.html#AEN7362

It's essentially the same thing as `select (col1, col2) from some_table` vs. `select col1, col2 from some_table`. The first one returns one column with an anonymous composite type that has two fields. The second one returns two columns from the table.

Comment: Now it works. thanks very much. it bothered me so long~~ i m new to this. so hard to find out. thanks again.

Comment: @user3895614 I understand that. This is one of those quirks that once you know them are quite logical but are totally stupid for someone not used to it (I'm actually not sure if this violates the SQL standard, but that's a different topic)

Comment: now, i get the new error when i add string "[abc]" as label.it said the syntax error at or near "[" , whats wrong with this? it already updates over 4000 rows

Comment: @user3895614 please ask a new question for that (include the full statement). A shot in the dark: `[abc]` is not a valid identifier. `"[abc]"` however would be.

Comment: "update postgresql with syntax errors" this is the new questions. is it because of this charcter "["?