# Dinstinct is not resulting the proper result

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I am new to Postgresql Database...i don't know what is problem but below query with `Distinct` results non-distinct results. please help on this issue.

```
 SELECT 
   Distinct(LEAST(name_1, name_2))||GREATEST(name_1, name_2) as keycol,
   name_1, 
   name_2, 
   latitude, 
   longitude 
 FROM england_intersection 
 order by keycol
 limit 100;`
```

Output result:  first field name is `kaycol`

```
"007 DriveBroccoli Road";"007 Drive";"Broccoli Road";51.5495845;-0.5349483
"007 DriveBroccoli Road";"Broccoli Road";"007 Drive";51.5495845;-0.5349483
"007 DriveGoldfinger Avenue";"007 Drive";"Goldfinger Avenue";51.5481323;-0.5347869
"007 DriveGoldfinger Avenue";"Goldfinger Avenue";"007 Drive";51.5481323;-0.5347869
"018Stour Valley Way";"018";"Stour Valley Way";50.7637982;-1.8722392
"018Stour Valley Way";"Stour Valley Way";"018";50.7637982;-1.8722392
"018Wimborne Road";"018";"Wimborne Road";50.7622107;-1.8746797
"018Wimborne Road";"Wimborne Road";"018";50.7622107;-1.8746797`
```

should return one of below

```
"10095";"100";"95";51.1280481;1.3347689
"10095";"95";"100";51.1280481;1.3347689
```

should return one of below

```
"10096";"100";"96";51.1280481;1.3347689
"10096";"96";"100";51.1280481;1.3347689`
```

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag, as this is a PostgreSQL question

Comment: `distinct` is ***not*** a function. It always operates on all columns in the select list. Your expression `(LEAST(name_1, name_2))||GREATEST(name_1, name_2)` simply creates an anonymous object type (which is a single column in the select list). See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25059838/330315 to understand what those  parentheses around the columns are really doing.